# Cakephp: Escape paginator prev link

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

I'm using the prev link for the Paginator component like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('&lsaquo;', array('escape'=> false), null, array('escape' => false)); ?>
```

This produces an escaped version of of `‹` when the link is active but does not escape the HTML when the link is disabled.

I'm using CakePHP 2.4

**Additional details:**

1. My model, controller and view is in the Plugin folder
2. My model is not using a database i.e. `var $useTable = false;`. I get my data
   via a web service.
3. I've overridden the paginate function in my model so that I can call the paginated web service.

Comment: have you tried `$this->Paginator->prev('&lsaquo;', array('escape'=> false), '&lsaquo;', array('escape' => false));`?

Comment: @Nunser yes. same result.

Comment: Just tested it on my site and it works, even with just `$this->Paginator->prev('&lsaquo;', array('escape'=> false))`, the problem must be somewhere else... Try clearing the cache and all that. Also, this doesn't suit your needs (to avoid escaping) `$this->Paginator->prev('<')`?

Comment: Me too tested on my site.. Working.. Question is why its not working there... Could you please update your question with whole view?

Comment: Did you override the paginate function in the Component or the Helper? Also, update the question with the whole view if possible.

Comment: @Nunser the paginate function is in the model i.e. in the app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Model/MyModel.php file. The view has nothing else relevant to this problem. I tried removing everything else in the view and left just this line in there i.e. $this->Paginator->prev(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [BoostCake](http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/)?

I was having the exact same problem. Active links were being escaped, but disabled ones were not.

I disabled the "BoostCake.BoostCakePaginator" plugin, and all is working fine, so I would assume a bug in that plugin. (I have no time to investigate at the moment, but if/when I do, I will report back.)

Comment: Yes I am. I'll investigate if that is the issue and update this thread accordingly.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Changing `return parent::prev($title, $options, $this->link($title),...);` to `return parent::prev($title, $options, '<a href="#">' . $title . '</a>',...);` is my temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

like gaurav sharma said, there is a bug.

you should replace `$this->link($title)` in return-value of `public function prev(...)` and `public function next(...)` in BoostCakePaginatorHelper.php (ln94 & ln121) by `$this->link($title, NULL, array('escape' => false))`

like this:

```
return parent::prev($title, $options, $this->link($title, NULL, array('escape' => false)), array_merge($options, array(
        'escape' => false,
        'class' => $disabled,
    )));
```